# LSTM configuration on cuDNN kernel

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to run LSTM with autoencoder configuration in Google Colab with gpu support. But I get following warning:

*WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU*

Generic GPU kernel is significantly slower than cuDNN kernel. So I searched for solution and found here (https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/) cuDNN kernel requirements for LSTM unit. Specifically:

```
activation == tanh
recurrent_activation == sigmoid
recurrent_dropout == 0
unroll is False
use_bias is True
Inputs, if use masking, are strictly right-padded.
Eager execution is enabled in the outermost context.
```

I thought that I found my problem in activation function which was 'relu', other cuDNN requirements are defaults in TF. Here is updated code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, activation='tanh',input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_outputs))
model.add(LSTM(200, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(100, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
```

But upon execution I get same warnings that cuDNN requirements are not met. What's wrong?

TF: 2.3.0

Comment: Just taking a shot here, but are you sure that CuDNN is correctly installed on this machine? It's something that might need to be installed in addition to your NVIDIA driver depending on where your starting point was.

Comment: It seems so: !nvcc -V results in nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

Comment: `nvcc` is the NVIDIA Cuda Compiler, which is different from CuDNN. You could check in your `/usr/lib/cuda/lib64` or `/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64` (depending on your CUDA version) for the files `libcudnn.so` and `cudnn.h`.

Comment: Look here for an introduction and installation instructions: https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn